# How to concat an array of objects to another at a specific index of it?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays,

```
const array1 = [{id: 1, name: 'abc'}, {id: 2, name: 'def'}];
const array2 = [{id: 1, name: 'xyz'}, {id: 3, name: 'mno'}];
```

Output should be:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'xyz'}, {id: 2, name: 'def'}, {id: 3, name: 'mno'}]
```

Merging the two arrays but with one of the object from the `array1` removed which can be easily achieved by filter though I'm doubtful on concating/merging objects of `array1` to the 2nd index position of `array2` part.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why is `name: 'abc'` removed?

Comment: This was literally the requirement, `name: 'abc'` object must be removed. Just a problem solving test, not the real world data

Comment: Are you trying to remove any item whose `name` property is `'abc'`?

Comment: Not actually but removing part is  known. Let me edit the question to make it less confusing

Comment: Why don't you concatenate then use filter?

Comment: Are you trying to concat, then sort by id, then remove duplicate ids? Are the input arrays always already sorted? Then use a simple merge.

Comment: Just have to reproduce output from the given two arrays and that's it. There is no requirement of sorting. Simple merge as in you are talking of concat?